# Play audio notification in Windows phone 8 when app is in background

Tags: c#, audio, windows-phone-8, background

I am developing a windows phone 8 which fetches location even app is in background.

I want to give user some audible notification ( Specifically play an audio mp3 file) when app is in background?  Is it possible? How can i acheive that?

Answer (score 1):

You can realize this feature with using toast notifications for Windows Phone 8 with Update 3 (OS version number 8.0.10492). In that OS version you can add custom sound to toast notification. Sound files can be in WAV, WMA, or MP3 format, must be less than 10 seconds long, and must be stored in the app’s installation directory or local storage folder.

[Using custom sounds in toasts on Windows Phone 8 Update 3](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/jj662938%28v=vs.105%29.aspx#BKMK_gdr3)

Comment: But this is for silverlight right? Can I get for normal one?